# Load Different Div using Ajax depending on Select Option

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, business-catalyst

I want to create a contact page that has a select box at the top and below a div containing a standard form.

However when the user selects a different option, the div containing the form changes to another form.

Something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="form1">Initial Form</option>
    <option value="form2">Form 2</option>
    <option value="form3">Form 3</option>
    <option value="form4">Form 4</option>
</select>


<div class="contactFormContainer">
    Initial Form Here
</div>
```

Then on the external page with all the forms i guess it would look like this.

```
<div class="form1">FORM content 1</div>
<div class="form2">FORM content 2</div>
<div class="form3">FORM content 3</div>
<div class="form4">FORM content 4</div>
```

Does this make any sense?

Thankyou

Comment: What's stopping you from creating it?

Comment: or maybe you can use tabs.

Comment: why use ajax? just get the all the data that has to be stored in all the above mentioned divs and show one div and hide the rest 3 divs at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>**[`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**</kbd> to load only `element` required from separate `html` page into the `div` as below.

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    var value=$(this).val(); //value would be form1, form2, form3 etc.,
    var url="yourhtmlpagename.html ."+value;
    $(".contactFormContainer").load(url,function(){
       //anything you want to do after form is loaded
    })
});
```